# How to declare a global variable of a module in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, typescript-typings

I have already required a global value to my global javascript context:

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

Because of some special reason, I have to require it in the global scope.

And I want to write a .d.ts file to declare the global variable with a strong type.
But how to?
'fs' is a module, not a type.

If I give the type like:  (in my types.d.ts file)

```
import * as fsi from 'fs';
declare const fs: fsi;
```

There will be an error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'fsi' as a type.

How to declare a global variable of a module in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Declare as `class` object instead of `type`

```
private fsi= new fsi()
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am afraid you misunderstood. I know how to use it in my .ts file, what I need is a .d.ts file to describe the variable. Just a definition file...